# typescript logged user data

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt

I'm trying to get current logged in data using typescript, JWT.

Below code is for generating token while login and store user data:

```
const generateToken = (user: ILoginedUser) => {
  const token = jwt.sign(user, "jswSecret", { expiresIn: "24h" });
  return token;
};
```

However when I try to use logged in user data in other controller its gives an error such as:

```
req.user._id
```

error seems like:

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2339)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of example code here is still missing, but I understand what you mean as I've recently worked with express as well.

How I fixed issues like this is by extending the express `Request` interface. Please note the additional properties MUST be optional.

```
export default interface ExtendedRequest extends Request {
    user?: User
}
```

As far as I'm aware, it's a clean solution which does not override the Request objects unless you manually declare them as such.

I would not recommend overriding the params and query properties, but you may declare your own body structure as well

```
export type ExtendedRequestBody = {
    oneProp: string;
    anotherProp: any;
}
```

and add the body type to your interface

```
export default interface ExtendedRequest extends Request {
    body: ExtendedRequestBody;
    user?: User;
```

If you aren't always receiving or setting the same properties, it is recommended to make them optional.

```
export type ExtendedRequestBody = {
    oneProp: string; // Always present
    anotherProp?: any; // Because of '?', the compiler will consider it as optional/not always present.
}
```

----- Edit: Made extended properties optional, which is required for this to work

Comment: I extend Request as shown but getting new error :

No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: ExtendedRequest, res: Response) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application<Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: ExtendedRequest, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>) => Promise<void>' is missing the following properties from type 'Application<Record<string, any>>': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and 61 more.ts(2769)

Comment: You may need to make `user` optional by adding a questionmark to it: `user?: User`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you want to add your own definitions to `express.Request`. This can be done as `TS` will combine all definitions for a type.

One easy way of doing this is to create a `type.d.ts` file at the root of your project and then add something similar to this in it:

```
declare module 'express' {
    export interface Request {
        user?: {
          _id: string; //or number, whatever the type is
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to instruct `ts` where to find these file definitions. So you can add this to `tsconfig.json`:

```
"files": [
  "type.d.ts"
]
```

Notes:

1. I create `user` as optional. This makes sense, as `Request` will def not have `user` defined on it at all times and this will force you do to a check
2. I've only added `_id` as a key on `user`. A better approach would be to create a type for it, where you are doing `auth` and import it in `type.d.ts`