# Extend response and request type with user logged in user in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, rest, request

I am using passportJS for cookie-based authentication. I extended the Request type so that I can get the user data when logged in from the request.

```
export interface IUserRequest extends express.Request {
  user?: Pick<IUser, "email" | "username" | "id">;
}
```

then I had to add `!` at all places where I am using `req.user` such as `req.user!.id`.
But still, I am getting this

CODE:

```
router.get("/", userLoggedIn, async (req: IUserRequest, res: Response) => {
  const tickets = await TicketController.getAllTickets();
  res.status(200).send({ tickets: tickets });
});
```

ERROR:

```
No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following error.     Argument of type '(req: IUserRequest, res: Response) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.       Type '(req: IUserRequest, res: Response) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.         Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.           Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to type 'IUserRequest'.             Types of property 'user' are incompatible.               Type 'User | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Pick<IUser, "email" | "username" | "id"> | undefined'.                 Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<IUser, "email" | "username" | "id">': email, username, idts(2769) index.d.ts(163, 5): The last overload is declared here.
```

[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMpP6.png)

I googled for multiple times, but all solutions are not working for me. maybe I am doing something wrong. checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73442073/15198732) which is very familiar to my problem.

Comment: type definition of the req parameter in your function is IUserRequest, which extends the express.Request type, but the type definition of the req parameter in the RequestHandler type expects a Request from the express package, can you check that?

Comment: you mean like this right? I have tried this.
`import express, { Response, Request } from "express";
export interface IUserRequest extends Request {
  user?: Pick<IUser, "email" | "username" | "id">;
}
`